# openstack octavia : amphora worker exception

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I am trying to run openstack Octavia, following along the directions here

https://docs.openstack.org/octavia/latest/contributor/guides/dev-quick-start.html

I ran into the following exception when I started Octavia-worker:

```
 2018-10-18 19:00:47.765 16044 INFO octavia.controller.queue.consumer [-]   Starting consumer...
 2018-10-18 19:00:49.103 16044 ERROR cotyledon._utils [-] Unhandled exception: ImportError: cannot import name opentype
 2018-10-18 19:00:49.103 16044 ERROR cotyledon._utils Traceback (most recent call last):
 2018-10-18 19:00:49.103 16044 ERROR cotyledon._utils   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cotyledon/_utils.py", line 95, in   exit_on_exception
 2018-10-18 19:00:49.103 16044 ERROR cotyledon._utils     yield
 2018-10-18 19:00:49.103 16044 ERROR cotyledon._utils   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cotyledon/_service.py", line 139, in _run
 2018-10-18 19:00:49.103 16044 ERROR cotyledon._utils     self.run()
 2018-10-18 19:00:49.103 16044 ERROR cotyledon._utils File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-  packages/octavia/controller/queue/consumer.py", line 41, in run
 2018-10-18 19:00:49.103 16044 ERROR cotyledon._utils     self.endpoints = [endpoint.Endpoint()]
 2018-10-18 19:00:49.103 16044 ERROR cotyledon._utils   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/octavia/controller/queue/endpoint.py", line 39, in __init__
 2018-10-18 19:00:49.103 16044 ERROR cotyledon._utils     invoke_on_load=True
```

I am using Octavia 1.0.2 with openstack pike. I am not sure what this import error "opentype" comes from. What package is missing? Thanks for your help.

Ranga

Answer (score 1):

The following fixed it (posted here for the benefit of others who might run into the same issue) :

```
pip install --upgrade pyasn1-modules
```

Now I see

```
 Unhandled exception: InvalidTarget: A server's target must have topic and server names specified:<Target server=neutron01>
2018-10-18 19:37:06.864 23338 ERROR cotyledon._utils Traceback (most recent call last):
   2018-10-18 19:37:06.864 23338 ERROR cotyledon._utils     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cotyledon/_utils.py", line 95, in    exit_on_exception
2018-10-18 19:37:06.864 23338 ERROR cotyledon._utils     yield
```

I uncommented the following in Octavia.conf which made that problem go away

```
 [oslo_messaging]
 topic = octavia_prov

# Topic for octavia's events sent to a queue
 event_stream_topic = neutron_lbaas_event
```

But it would be nice if I knew what I was doing.